# Removing attributes from nested array in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I am trying to filter out some attributes from an array in D3. The array contains the values of a csv file.

This all worked well for a small csv file doing it like this:

```
d3.csv("foods.csv", function(data) {
data.forEach(function(v){ delete v.name });
data.forEach(function(v){ delete v.created_at });
});
```

This is what the first array looks like: [image]

But when I try to do it for a bigger csv file I get an error saying : "devtools was disconnected from the page. once page is reloaded devtools will automatically reconnect". 
This is what the 2nd array looks like. [image]

Why is this not working for the 2nd array? Is the array too big or should I try to address the values recursively because I already tried doing it like this:

```
function deleteCitation(v) {
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]' ) {
    v.forEach(deleteCitation);
}
else {
    delete v.citation;
 }
}

d3.csv("compounds_foods.csv", function(data) {
   data.forEach(deleteCitation);

   print(data);
});
```

Comment: Woah, loading an array of 740k+ items in the client looks a bit too much, are you sure you need all those data points? Can't a sort of pre-aggregation be done server side first?

Answer (score 0):

I never loaded an CSV with **740 thousand rows**. However, I believe you have some alternatives:

Use a *row conversion function*, or an accessor function:

```
d3.csv("foods.csv", deleteCitation, function(data) {
//the rest of the code
```

And then declare the conversion function:

```
function deleteCitation(d){
    delete d.name;
    delete d.created_at;
    return d;
}
```

I didn't benchmarked it, maybe the conversion function takes the same time that your `forEach` (they do pretty much the same thing), but I believe that it's worth to check if this is quicker than calling your `deleteCitation` function for each object inside the `data` array.

The second alternative is simpler: don't remove those two properties, just leave them there and don't use them!

When you load an CSV to your `data` array you don't have to use all the properties in each object for your visualisation. You can simply ignore them. It's possible that you waste more processing time manipulating that **huge** array than simply leaving those extra two objects there.

The third alternative is the logical one: as there is absolutely *no way* you're gonna use 740k objects in a dataviz, consider filtering/reducing/cropping this CSV before sending it to the client side.